# Primefaces Application doesnt not work

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Hi I am using primefaces 5.3 version and jsf 2.2 and java 1.8, I have a page with primefaces datatable lazyloading but it works in local machine but ends up with error while i deploy in remote machine.Do i have any error in my configuration.

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>almightyenterprises</groupId>
    <artifactId>almightyenterprises</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.51</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.ez-vcard</groupId>
            <artifactId>ez-vcard</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:hx="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
    <title>SMS Dasboard</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/images/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="../assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Top -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <a href="index.xhtml"><img src="../assets/images/logo.png"
                            class="brand" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right">
                        <div class="links">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#"><img
                                        src="../assets/images/settings.png" alt="" /> Settings</a></li>
                                <li><p:inputText name="" type="button"
                                        value="SMS Balance : 89,000"
                                        styleClass="btn balancebtn btn-default" /></li>
                                <li><a href="#"><img src="../assets/images/logout.png"
                                        alt=""></img> Logout</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Top End -->

        <!--   Main End  -->

        <section class="mainsec">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!--  Sidebar  -->
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <div class="headings pink">
                            <h3>latest activities</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="contentsec">
                            <p>Added 200 new items for 2 groups, Added 200 new items for
                                2 groups, Added 200 new items for 2 groups</p>
                            <div class="date">
                                <img src="../assets/images/date.png" alt="" /> 19.01.2017
                            </div>
                            <div class="time">
                                <img src="../assets/images/time.png" alt="" /> 11.12
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contentsec" style="opacity: 0.3;">
                            <p>Added 200 new items for 2 groups, Added 200 new items for
                                2 groups, Added 200 new items for 2 groups</p>
                            <div class="date">
                                <img src="../assets/images/date.png" alt="" /> 18.01.2017
                            </div>
                            <div class="time">
                                <img src="../assets/images/time.png" alt="" /> 12.12
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="contentsec" style="opacity: 0.3;">
                            <p>Added 200 new items for 2 groups, Added 200 new items for
                                2 groups, Added 200 new items for 2 groups</p>
                            <div class="date">
                                <img src="../assets/images/date.png" alt="" /> 17.01.2017
                            </div>
                            <div class="time">
                                <img src="../assets/images/time.png" alt="" /> 09.12
                            </div>
                            <div class="border"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--  Sidebar End -->

                <!--  CenterSec  -->

                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <div class="centersec">
                        <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                            <div class="card-block">
                                <h3>Add Items</h3>
                                <p>
                                    <h:form styleClass="form-group" id="uppperForm">
                                        <label>Name</label>
                                        <p:inputText styleClass="col-lg-12 input-group" />
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input class="col-lg-12 input-group" />
                                        <label>Phone No</label>
                                        <p:inputText styleClass="col-lg-12 input-group" />
                                        <label>Group</label>
                                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                        <p:inputText styleClass="col-lg-9 input-group input1" />
                                        <p:inputText name="" type="button" value="+ Add"
                                            styleClass="col-lg-2 btn1" />
                                        <p:inputText name="" type="button" value="Add Contact"
                                            styleClass="btn editbtn btn-default" />
                                    </h:form>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="additems">
                            <div class="headings yellow">
                                <h3>
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample"
                                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Add
                                        Items</a>
                                </h3>
                                <span>1612</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="filter">
                                <img src="../assets/images/items.png" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="listing">
                                <h:form id="itemsListingForm">
                                    <p:dataTable rows="20" lazy="true"
                                        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                        rowKey="#{item.itemCode}" id="itemDetailTable"
                                        widgetVar="itemDetailTablewVar" scrollRows="20"
                                        liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="430" scrollable="true"
                                        value="#{productBean.jobLazyDataItemList}" var="item"
                                        filteredValue="#{productBean.itemModelList}"
                                        selectionMode="multiple" editable="true" editMode="cell"
                                        selection="#{productBean.selectedItemList}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <p:outputPanel>
                                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" styleClass="col-lg-12 search"
                                                    onkeyup="PF('itemDetailTablewVar').filter()"
                                                    placeholder="Search" />

                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <p:ajax event="cellEdit"
                                            listener="#{productController.onCellEditTableComplete(item)}"
                                            update="@([id$=itemDetailTable])" />
                                        <p:column headerText="Item Code" filterBy="#{item.itemCode}"
                                            styleClass="col-lg-2" filterStyle="display:none;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{item.itemCode}"
                                                style="font-weight: bold" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Item Name" filterBy="#{item.itemName}"
                                            styleClass="col-lg-8" filterStyle="display:none;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{item.itemName}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Item Price" filterBy="#{item.itemPrice}"
                                            styleClass="col-lg-2" filterStyle="display:none;">
                                            <p:cellEditor>
                                                <f:facet name="output">
                                                    <h:outputText value="#{item.itemPrice}" />
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <f:facet name="input">
                                                    <p:inputText value="#{item.itemPrice}" style="width:96%" />
                                                </f:facet>
                                            </p:cellEditor>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:dataTable>

                                </h:form>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="addgroup">
                            <div class="headings green">
                                <h3>Add Contact</h3>
                                <span>798</span>
                            </div>

                            <h:form id="contactListForm">
                                <div class="filter">
                                    <img src="../assets/images/groups.png" alt="" />
                                    <p:selectOneMenu value="#{productBean.selectedGroup}"
                                        styleClass="select pull-right">
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue=""
                                            noSelectionOption="true"></f:selectItem>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{productBean.contactGroups}"
                                            var="group" itemLabel="#{group.groupName}"
                                            itemValue="#{group.groupName}"></f:selectItems>
                                        <p:ajax listener="#{productController.filterContact}"
                                            event="change" update="contactListForm" />
                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                                </div>
                                <div class="listing">
                                    <p:dataTable rows="20" lazy="true"
                                        paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                                        rowKey="#{contact.contactId}" id="contactDetailTable"
                                        widgetVar="contactDetailTablewVar" scrollRows="20"
                                        liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="430" scrollable="true"
                                        value="#{productBean.jobLazyDataContactList}" var="contact"
                                        filteredValue="#{productBean.contactModelList}"
                                        selectionMode="multiple" editable="true" editMode="cell"
                                        selection="#{productBean.selectedContactList}">
                                        <f:facet name="header">
                                            <p:outputPanel>
                                                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" styleClass="col-lg-12 search"
                                                    onkeyup="PF('contactDetailTablewVar').filter()"
                                                    placeholder="Search" />
                                            </p:outputPanel>
                                        </f:facet>
                                        <p:column headerText="Contact Name"
                                            filterBy="#{contact.contactFirstName}"
                                            filterStyle="display:none;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{contact.contactFirstName}" />
                                            <h:outputText value="#{contact.contactSecondName}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column headerText="Contact Number"
                                            filterBy="#{contact.contactMobile}"
                                            filterStyle="display:none;">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{contact.contactMobile}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:dataTable>
                                </div>
                            </h:form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--  CenterSec End -->

                <!--  RighrSec  -->

                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="rightsec">
                        <textarea name="Type Your Message Here..." cols="" rows="8"
                            class="col-lg-12" placeholder="Type Your Message Here..."></textarea>
                        <p>maximum characters : 200</p>
                        <textarea name="Type Your Message Here..." cols="" rows="14"
                            class="col-lg-12" placeholder="Preview..."></textarea>
                        <input name="" type="button" value="Update"
                            class="btn updatebtn btn-default pull-right" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--  RighrSec End  -->

            </div>
        </div>
        </section>

        <!--   Main End  -->

        <!--   Footer   -->

        <footer>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>&copy; Company Name. 2017</p>
        </div>

        </footer>
        <!--   Footer End  -->
    </div>


    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <!-- <script src="../assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
</h:body>
</html>
```

**log**

```
com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(Ljavax/faces/context/FacesContext;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.DynamicResourcesPhaseListener.afterPhase(DynamicResourcesPhaseListener.java:31)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(Unknown Source)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment i figured it both primefaces 5.3 and 6 were added hence it didnt work , I removed the 5.3 jar now its working

Comment: Then it could not have worked on your other server as well if it is identical for the rest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a version mismatch between primeface vs. javax.faces to me. Can you upgrade to primeface 6? Your 5.3 does not know the *ResourceUtils#getComponentResources*. Which is a tad hard to see, because primeface shits on the @since-Annotation in their javadoc ;)

Comment: If this is the case (and it very well could be) the two versions of the app are not the same. That should have been very easy for them to find out shouldn't it?

Comment: yes its maven included both jars 5.3 and 6.0 hence there was a mismatch in version

Comment: @vivekshankar: maven never does that on its own and only 5.3 is in it. So maven is not to blame

Comment: Nope i didnt tell like that @Kukeltje the reason is i was working in 5.3 and changed it to 6.0. While building the war i didnt clean the maven and directly gave run as maven install hence it had the old version and included the new one 6.0